# I am having issues with a repeating while loop in a switch statement, the loop continues to repeat

Tags: while-loop

I'm a newbie coder and for a class I was required to make a vending machine-like code. However, I used a switch statement as part of it. An issue I faced is that in those if statements I added a check.  The check was to ask if the user would like to continue or not, but for some reason it repeats even after an input. I wasn't entirely sure if this question was asked before, but a lot of my friends share the issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw52 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String choice;
    String answer = "";
    int cr = 0;
    int wb = 0;
    int ch = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    boolean check =  true;
    double cost2;
    double discount;
    double change = 0;
    double cost = 0;
    double money = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    do {
        answer = "";
        System.out.println("Select an option in the vending machine. \n 
Crunch:$1.50 \n Water bottle:$2.00 \n Chips:$1.00 \n Ketchup:$4.00 \n 
Juice:$2.50");
        choice = keyboard.nextLine();
        switch(choice.toUpperCase()){
        case "CRUNCH":
            cost += 1.5;
            cr ++;
            counter ++;
            System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
            while(check = true) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Yes or no?");
            answer = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                check = false;
            }else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                check = false;
            }else {
                System.out.println("Bad input.");
            }
            }
        case "WATER BOTTLE":
            cost += 2.00;
            wb++;
            counter ++;
            System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
            while(check = true) {
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Yes or no?");
                answer = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                    check = false;
                }else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                    check = false;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Bad input.");
                }
                }
        case "CHIPS":
            cost += 1.00;
            ch++;
            counter ++;
            System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
            System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
            while(check = true) {
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Yes or no?");
                answer = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                    check = false;
                }else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                    check = false;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Bad input.");
                }
                }
        case "KETCHUP":
            cost += 5.00;
            k++;
            counter ++;
            System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
            while(check = true) {
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Yes or no?");
                answer = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                    check = false;
                }else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                    check = false;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Bad input.");
                }
                }
        case "JUICE":
            cost += 2.50;
            j++;
            counter ++;
            System.out.println("Cost: " + cost);
            while(check = true) {
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue? Yes or no?");
                answer = keyboard.nextLine();
                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                    check = false;
                }else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
                    check = false;
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Bad input.");
                }
                }
        default: 
            System.out.println("Not a choice! Use exact names.");
            answer = "yes";
        }
    }while(!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"));
    counter /= 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter;i++) {
        discount = (double)(Math.random()*.1)+.1;
        cost2 = cost * discount;
        cost -= cost2;
    }   
    while(money < cost) {
    System.out.println("How much money would you like to use to pay?");
    money = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if (money < cost) {
        System.out.println("That's not enough money.");
    }
    }
    double Q = cost / .25;
    double D = (cost % .25) / .10;
    double N = ((cost % .25) % .10) / .05 ;
    double P = (((cost % .25) % .10) %.05) /.01;
    System.out.println("The items you bought are: \n Crunch Bars: " + cr + 
"\n Water Bottles: " + wb + "\n Chips: " + ch + "\n Ketchup: " + k + "\n 
Juice: " + j);
    System.out.println("Your change is: $" + ((Q * .25) + (D * .1) + (N * 
.05) + (P*.01))); 
    }

}
```

Please excuse my messy coding style. I personally like it better, but I know a lot of people find it strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never allows the user to input "no" into the `answer` variable. So your code always forces the user to intput "yes" or it shows the message "Bad Input".

You have this `if` statement in each one of your `while` loops. Both `if` and `else if` check the exact same condition. I assume you were probably wanting one of them to check for the answer "no" and the `check` variable never gets assigned to `false` unless "yes" is chosen:

```
answer = keyboard.nextLine();
if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {  //this is same condition as next if line.
    check = false;
}else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) { //this is same condition as prior if line.
    check = false;
}else {
    System.out.println("Bad input.");
}
```

Also, this is your main issue. You are ALWAYS assigning `check` to `true` in the `while` loop condition. you want to use the `==` operator.

This assigns true to the check variable in your code:

```
while(check = true) {
```

You actually want to do this:

```
while(check == true) {
```

I recommend using an IDE with a debugger that allows you to systematically step through your code and see what is happening with each line of code as it executes. It will help you find logic problems like this one.

Comment: Thank you for that, but it still continues even if I input Yes, which is the issue. The output would be:  Select an option in the vending machine. 
    Crunch:$1.50 
    Water bottle:$2.00 
    Chips:$1.00 
    Ketchup:$4.00 
    Juice:$2.50
    Crunch
    Cost: 1.5
    Do you want to continue? Yes or no?
    Yes
    Do you want to continue? Yes or no?

Comment: @BoofyBee oh, I see what you are saying now. check my edit about your `while` condition.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel slightly dumb atm. Anyways, there's a bunch more bugs, but I think I got them. Thanks again!

Comment: @BoofyBee no worries, these are common issues a lot of programmers go through when starting out. I made the same mistakes and that is why I can pick them out, from the experience of finding my own bugs, lol... Glad I could help. If this post answered your question, then please mark it as the accepted answer. Refer to this stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers